# Understanding number in PDF code

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I was wondering if somebody would be able to tell me what the following numbers mean after I decrypt the file.  I am having corrupted file issues and I am trying to figure out where the corruption is occuring so I can try to fix it in the future.

The numbers in question are in between asterisks in the code below:

```
h
W
n
q
/ttf37 141 Tf
0.000 0.000 0.000 sc
BT
1 0 0 1 **1980.000000 12593.000000** Tm
(8953 - 18) Tj
ET
Q
Q
q
720 12518 m
1875 12518 l
1875 12308 l
720 12308 l
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [PDF Reference 1.7](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html), in particular Table 5.5, on page 406, for the definition of the `Tm` (standing for *Transformation matrix*) operator.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Alex Pigeon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227818/501196) said, `Tm` specifies a transformation matrix that will be applied to all following operators. A transformation matrix can be used for rotation, translation, scaling etc. of graphic operations, and it can be combined with previous transformations.

You can also use the term [Affine Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) for more details on this besides the PDF spec.